# I want to travel Australia, how can I get visa without passport?

Tags: passports, indian-citizens, international-travel, australia

If I have no passport and I want to travel Australia, is it possible?
If yes then what is the process for that ?
If compulsory required passport, then how I can get urgent passport in India and what is process for that ?

Comment: Passports are required for almost all international travel, except when there are _very_ close relations between the traveller's country of citizenship and the country being travelled to.

Comment: You MUST have an Australian passport. Many countries have urgent approval systems by payment of extra $. In NZ a passport can be obtained in a few days at very large $. Your country's websites should advise what applies in India.

Answer (score 9):

**You can't**.  Entry to Australia requires "[a valid passport or other acceptable travel document](https://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Ente/Goin/Arrival/Travel-Documents-for-Entry-to-Australia)", which for an Indian citizen means an Indian passport.

Once you have the passport, you will need to apply for a [Visitor visa](https://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Visa-1/600-) (subclass 600).  At time of writing, [these take about three weeks to process in India](http://india.embassy.gov.au/ndli/09012013.html)

Comment: Any another option to get temporary passport?

Comment: @NimeshGami generally not.  Are you in a hurry for some particular reason?

Comment: @Phoog - yes, my friends are going for fun so. :(

Comment: @NimeshGami That isn't a good reason to demand a passport urgently.

Comment: @DumbCoder  - Yes you are right dear.